# Using AWS cloudwatch to monitor nginx ngx_http_stub_status_module

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

How can we monitor ngx_http_stub_status_module with AWS cloudwatch?
Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what exactly you need to monitor from ngx_http_stub_status_module. It provides a lot of info. What is critical to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check into [awsmonitors on GitHub](https://github.com/newsapps/awsmonitors).

I'll probably implement something using this or similar, and update this answer.